# Windows phone 8- See caller id

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Can I build app that set live tile with a number of person who called me?

I think that it should be a task scheduled agent, but I can't find where can I add something like when there is a call, see his caller id and show it in the live tile.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't Windows Phone doesn't have an API for this data.